# Why does the output of this code become jumbled up after the if statement?

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.System;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Writingclean{
    public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    try{

        System.out.println("File Name:");
        String FileName = input.next();
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter( FileName + ".txt");
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);


        System.out.println("How many questions do you want?");

        String y = input.next();
        int NumberofQuestions = Integer.parseInt(y);

        int QuestionCounter = 1;
        int x = 0;
        while(x < NumberofQuestions){


        System.out.println("Question " + QuestionCounter + ":"); String    Question = input.nextLine();  
        System.out.println("Option 1:"); String Op1 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Option 2:"); String Op2 = input.nextLine(); 
        System.out.println("Option 3:"); String Op3 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Correct Answer (Option Number):"); String An1 = input.nextLine();



         pw.println(Question);
         pw.println(Op1);
         pw.println(Op2);
         pw.println(Op3);
         pw.println(An1);

         x++;
         QuestionCounter++;


    }
         pw.close();    
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("Invalid File Name!");
    }



    }
}
```

I am currently working on a studying-ish type app and have come across this issue:

I want it so the user can choose how many questions they want, hence the while statement (If there is a better way to do this please let me know). However, after the while statment the consle seems to skip on of the 'input.nextLine();'s. Meaning there is no question only options.

Any way to fix this?

Output looks like this:

File Name:
**EXAMPLE**
How many questions do you want?
**EXAMPLE**
Question 1:
Option 1:

Comment: try using input.next() instead of input.nextLine()

Comment: Thanks! Well... No! But thanks. I managed to fix it by making all of the inputs to 'input.nextLine'. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Don't mention it, and yeah, you don't need to import anything from java.lang package. Its included by default in java.

Answer (score 0):

You may use BufferedReader instead of scanner class
Syntax is as follows

```
BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String x=input.readLine();
```

make sure you import the java.io.BufferedReader and java.io.InputStreamReader classes.
Also handle the IOException.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the way to fix it is to make all of the inputs the same way. Meaning all of the Strings are equal to:

input.nextLine();

rather than some being

input.next();